# Library not found | linker command failed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa

I try to build and run my Xcode project but I continue to see it fail due to this issue below.

I tried to clean and build - didn't work

set bitcoede to no - didn't work

reinstall cocoa pods/updatecocoapods - didn't work

Troubleshooting cocoa pods with their link (https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html) - didn't work

any ideas? I am using the Firebase cocoa pods and I am in the process of creating a user login page.

ld: library not found for -lPods

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Can you verify that "libPods.a" is listed in your target's "Build Phases" under "Link Binary With Libraries". And Target settings --> Library Search Path --> $(inherited)

Answer (score 2):

I had something similar.  My project is setup a bit differently.

1) First I change my .xcodeproj to a workspace. From "Files->Save As Workspace.." menu option.

2)Ensured that in my project folder that "pod install" had worked and had all the frameworks under the pods folder.

3)Drag the pod.xcodeproj from the project folder into xcode to the top of the project list.

Compiling now succeeded for me.
Hope this helps if you are still having this issue.